# Is the 1 year time line for a proposal to gain followers from its proposal or from the start of the commit phase?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Apparently, there is a 1 year time limit for a proposal in Area 51 to be launched. Is this from the proposal time or from when it enters the commit phase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, judging from the [official annoucement](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/closing-a-proposal-after-1-year-in-definition-or-commitment) of this feature, the answer is: "both".

The clock start ticking twice: first in the instant the proposal is created, hence entering the Definition mode, and when the proposal reach the Commitment phase, fresh timer of 1 year starts ticking again.

So it means that a proposal must launch within 2 years at most.